# WCF Client generation possible based on ServiceContract alone?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, soap

I have a Visual Studio Solution in which a WCF server is contained; the service is defined as an interface using the `ServiceContract` attribute. The service is finally hostes via an instance of `ServiceHost` using `HttpBinding`, which is the intended behaviour.

In the same solution, there is a client; currently the hosted service is consumed by starting the server manually and generating a proxy class using "Add Service Reference", which can be updated as soon as the server is running.

While this works in the sense that the outcome is as desired, I wonder if it is possible to remove the manual start of the server to update the service reference in the client. Is it possible to build the client by just sharing the `DataContract` attributed interface between server and client without actually running the server and importing the service definition manually in the client? If yes, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use svcutil to generate proxy, but even that require WSDL metadata to generate proxy and that is usually available by starting service,  you can save it once from the running server and you can use that to generate proxy without starting server later on.

see different options http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33297/WCF-Proxy-Generation-Options

I personally like hand crafted client as I have better control on code/error handling and I can use shared DTOs from common dll.

Comment: Well thanks, but in fact I would like to remove the necessity to actually host the service just to update the client; is it possible to automatically generate a client based on just the innermost service definition, i.e. the `DataContract` attributed class, and the knowledge that it will be hosted via http?

Comment: Using svcuitl you need to host service once and generated WSDL file but then all client can use generated WSDL and service not require to be running.

Comment: if your client are using .NET, i will suggest to use hand crafted client proxy in shared dll, it is quite simple see, http://www.codemag.com/article/0809101.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a common data contract, shared between the client(s) and host, to maintain the interface between both sides. That's what I do with this big data sync WS built on BasicHttpBinding.

In a nutshell, I have a host project, with a service contract and the functioning/processing code, referencing a very small project (and DLL) containing only the data contract class definition; just class, constructor, variables and in/out parameters.

That same small project containing the data contract is also referenced by a client-side project that handles all of the interaction between our client programs and the Sync WS. We actually have every web service call (from the simplest Ping() function to the most complicated RetryFileUpload() function) running through that data contract. All the string-based parameters and binary data is passed through the data contract class, then seriailized or deserialized on the receiving end.

Having said that, this approach only works when you have .NET code on both the client and host. We also have Android and iOS clients that are forced to emulate this behavior ... which isn't a big deal, obviously. But this is the approach we took.

Comment: Well thanks four your answer; but could you please be a bit more specific on how the client is build just based on the `DataContract` attributed class? This is exactly the part that puzzles me.

Comment: Let me see if I can dig up a diagram .. that explains it better.

Comment: Couldn't find a diagram, unfortunately, that shows what I'm talking about. I guess in short, have your client and host solutions reference a single project containing your DataContract only, that way both the host and client always have the same interface.

Comment: Okay, sort of figured it out - the client code must derive from `ClientBase<T>` where `T` is the shared interface; thanks a lot for your help! This is basically what the proxa class generator does - however the code for `T` is duplicated this way.